# Postgres materialized views with hot standby

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

We are using Postgres (9.3) Hot Standby to build a read-only copy of a database. We have a UI which reads from a materialized view.

When we try to read from the materialized view in the standby database, the query hangs.

The materialized view takes ~10 seconds to rebuild in the master database. We've waited over 30 minutes for the query in the standby database and it seems to never complete.

Notably, the materialized view does exist in the standby database. We can't refresh it of course (since the DB is read only)

We can't find anything in the documentation which indicates that materialized views can't be used in standby databases, but that appears to be the case.

Has anyone got this to work, and/or what is the recommended work-around?

Comment: Works fine for me in 9.5. What does [`pg_stat_activity.waiting`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) say for your standby query? Where/when/how are you refreshing your view on the primary? Does your query involve other tables?

Comment: Could be a locking problem. Look in `pg_locks` if the session is waiting for a lock held by somebody else.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yes. There's an exclusive lock held by the recovery process. This would seem to be a problem, since that process is always running. Not sure what to do?

Comment: Here's the locks:  postgres 14064  0.0  1.1 290108 48324 ?        Ss   05:22   0:03  \_ postgres: startup process   waiting for 00000001000000060000000E
postgres 23242  0.0  0.0   4508   808 ?        S    22:02   0:00  |   \_ sh -c /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_standby /var/lib/postgresql/master_archive 00000001000000060000000E pg_xlog/RECOVERYXLOG 00000001000000060000000C
postgres 23243  0.0  0.0   4372   796 ?        S    22:02   0:00  |       \_ /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_standby /var/lib/postgresql/master_archive 00000001000000060000000E pg_xlog/RECOVERYXLOG 00000001000000060000000C

Comment: It is ok for the recovery process to lock the view, but the lock should be released again. Is there a lock on the materialized view on the primary?

Answer (score 0):

According to PostgreSQL Documentation  -  [Hot Standby](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/hot-standby.html) there is a way to handle Query Conflicts by assigning proper values to

> max_standby_archive_delay & max_standby_streaming_delay

that define the maximum allowed delay in WAL application. In your case  a high  value may be preferable.